# QT QSqlDatabase open() function creates a sqlite database

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I'm trying to open a sqlite database file in QT using .open() function and if the file doesn't exit, .open() doesn't return a false, it just creates a new file in the given directory. My code:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("C:/sqlite/newDB.db");

    if(!db.open()){
        ui->test->setText("Fail");
    }
    else{
        ui->test->setText("Success");
    }
```

How to make it return a true or false ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't make it return true or false, this is how it works. . .

However, you can check for file existence before opening the database using `QFile::exists("C:\\sqlite\\newDB.db")`. After that, if it is existent you can try a query like this to make sure it is not corrupted:

```
QSqlQuery q;
if(!q.exec("SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ;")){
    //corrupt sqlite file
}
```

the final code may look like this:

```
if(!QFile::exists("C:\\sqlite\\newDB.db")){
    //file does not exist
}
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("C:\\sqlite\\newDB.db");
if(!db.open()){
    //Database open error
}
{
    QSqlQuery q;
    if(!q.exec("SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ;")){
        //corrupt or invalid sqlite file
}
```

Comment: Did you actually test this? Because the newly created database will also contain the system table.

Comment: @CL. , yes, this is tested. sorry, what is *the system table*?

Comment: It's the table you're trying to access. Anyway, I misunderstood the logic; this should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. However, QT documentation says "Opens the database connection using the current connection values. Returns true on success; otherwise returns false"

Comment: @ReeSSult , and in case of a non existent sqlite file, it creates a new empty database and connects to it, thus it succeeds and returns true. . .
since this behavior is not suitable to you, we check if the file exists first. . .